# Search for text wrap with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have the following HTML-code:

```
<div id="Test">
  My selected Link
  <a href="link1.html">My Link 1</a>
  <a href="link2.html">My Link 2</a>
</div>
```

I need to **find the text string** inside:

```
<div id="Test"></div>
```

and **wrap it with a tag**. It will always be only one text string inside

```
<div id="Test"></div>
```

but the text will have different locations in the code, for example:

```html
<div id="Test">
  <a href="link1.html">My Link 1</a> Another Selected Link
  <a href="link2.html">My Link 2</a>
</div>
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

```html
<div id="Test">
  <a href="link1.html">My Link 1</a>
  <h2>Another Selected Link</h2>
  <a href="link2.html">My Link 2</a>
</div>
```

So to sum up: find the only text string inside the div (but not in the children tags) and wrap it with a tag.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps in your specific case

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/adabub/1/edit)**

```
$('#Test').contents(':not(a)').wrap('<h2/>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/contents/
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Simple solution, thank you. I get a lot of empty <h2></h2> tags between each <a>-tag. Can you describe how to get rid of all those empty tags as it took all the empty lines with spaces as a "content".